Kids movie about kids kept as slaves in an underground cave, monsters all around, on HBO?
I'm trying to find a movie I saw as a kid. It was a kids movie, pretty cheesy I think, about a kid who was on his way to the store to buy something (for his father maybe?) and winds up in an underground cave, thing, kept as a slave with a whole bunch of others kids, and these "scary" monsters. The kids are forced to do hard labor and operate machinery and are starved. The ending was one of the kids pokes a hole in the ceiling and the light kills all the monsters, except for the one he be-friended because I guess he wasn't really a monster.
It's totally a life lesson movie.
One of the weird highlights is, while the kid is in the jail cell, someone gives him a "Bunch Bar" that look awful lot like a Crunch bar from nestle, but isn't...
It is not a movie one would ever find anywhere (like little monsters or gremlins, etc.) BUT it can't be that obscure because I'm sure i saw it on HBO. It would come on in the mornings.
I've looked for this movie for YEARS everywhere..and zero trace. 
This would have been out before 2000..probably like early to mid 90s. but maybe much sooner...

I guess this could be the child movie Jacob Two Two Meets the Hooded Fang.

Jacob Two Two Meets The Hooded Fang is about a young boy who strives to be heard. He is nicknamed "Two-Two" for having to say things twice to be heard. One day, he decided to buy the groceries for his parents. There is a misunderstanding by the clerk, so Jacob finds himself in court. He is sentenced Two Years, Two months, two weeks and two minutes in the Children's Prison hundreds of miles away from civilization.
It is a dark, dirty dungeon-like place where the children work and are kept in cells. There are the three head characters, Master Fish, a fish/human, Mistress Fowl, a bird like woman and the Hooded Fang himself. They also have green henchmen who spray "slime resistors" at the children to prevent them escaping. Two child agents try to help him out, as the children also come up with a plan for escape.

The problem is, there are 2 movies, one from 1978 and one from 1999, so i am not sure which one you have seen.
You can find the 1978 version in 7 parts on youtube, in this part you can sse the scene where the green henchmen are killed by light (at 9:00) and that they befriend with the villians afterwards. Also they get chocolate bars, gumdrops, and other tasty treats, but I did not searched the specific part where the scene is in.  



here is a trailer of the 1999 version:



